# How to search for NSMutablearray content in substring of a NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

I created an `NSMutableArray` and am searching/matching the content of array with `NSString's` substring but how to do it?

```
NSMutableArray *tmparray = {@"PPG" , @"AG" , @"HD" };
NSString *tmpstring = @"MAAPPG";

if ([tmparray containsObject:tmpstring] ) {
  NSLog(@"String found");
}
```

But it's not happening because tmparray contain "PPG" not "MAAPPG" how to search for substring matching ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `NSPredicate` to do this, but it may be slow. Here's a simpler approach along the lines of what your trying:

```
NSMutableArray *tmparray = {@"PPG" , @"AG" , @"HD" };
NSString *tmpstring = @"MAAPPG";
NSRange *tmprange;
for(NSString *string in tmparray) { 
    tmprange = [tmpstring rangeOfString:string];
    if (tmprange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"String found");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The break you have put in gives you the +1 :)

Comment: Should be `rangeOfString` in place of `rangeOfSubstring`

Answer (score 2):

how about this

```
for(NSString *arrString in tmparray){
 if([tmpstring rangeOfString:arrString].location != NSNotFound){
   NSLog(@"String found");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *tmparray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"PPG" , @"AG" , @"HD",nil];
    NSString *tmpstring = @"MAAPPG";
    NSRange textRange;
    for(NSString *string in tmparray)
    {
        textRange =[tmpstring rangeOfString:string];
        if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            NSLog(@"String found ");
        }
    }
```

check this by using other substrings also...